# AWS policy grantig access to one CodeArtifact package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact, aws-iam-policy

I'm trying to create a policy granting read-only access to one python package on CodeArtifact.

This is what I've got so far, but it seems to be granting access to all packages in the repository (and not just `myPackage1`):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:GetServiceBearerToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-central-1:REDACTED:domain/REDACTED_DOMAIN"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-central-1:REDACTED:repository/REDACTED_DOMAIN/REDACTED_REPO"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:DescribePackage",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionAsset"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-central-1:REDACTED:package/REDACTED_DOMAIN/REDACTED_REPO/pypi/*/myPackage1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What do I need to chage to limit acces to just one package?